# How to override a CSS property to use the attribute value

Tags: css

You have the following HTML:

```
<object height="400"></object>
```

In the CSS, you have:

```
object { height: auto; }
```

Is there a way to omit the CSS `height: auto` without deleting it? In other words, is there a way to make the attribute value override the stylesheet?

Comment: `height="400"` isn't inline CSS, it's an attribute with a value. Inline CSS would be `style="height:400px"`

Comment: You are completely correct, I have edited my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

use the style tag on an element:

`<object style="height:400px"></object>`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `:not` selector:

http://cssdeck.com/labs/bgv0buyf

```
object:not([height]) {
  height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS in the `style` attribute will override that defined against an element. If it's not doing that in your code, then there is likely some other CSS rule being applied.

I'd suggest using a DOM inspector such as the one in chrome developer tools (right click -> inspect element) to see what's going on.

For more info, read up on [CSS specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/).

Answer (score 0):

```
<object style="height:400px !important;"></object>
```

css inline statement overrides ext stylesheet references.
use developer tools to figure out css overrides.